# How can I place a variable number of images in a defined space using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is a picture of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

I want to have various lines of text, probably in a `<p>`, with a variable number of images in front (up to 3, with two variations each, empty circles and filled dots, as shown).  Each item can have zero to three images.  If showing, blue is always on the left, green in the middle and yellow on the right.

I tried putting the images as a `background-image` within a `span`, but could not figure out how to make the margins/padding to work in this variable condition.

```
<style>
  p { display: block; }
  span { padding: 0 36px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
  .outlineS { padding: 10px 12px; background-image: url('img/circle-blue.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
  .outlineD { padding: 10px 12px; background-image: url('img/dot-blue.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
  .graphicS { padding: 10px 12px; background-image: url('img/circle-green.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
  .graphicD { padding: 10px 12px; background-image: url('img/dot-green.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
  .textS { padding: 10px 12px; background-image: url('img/circle-yellow.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
  .textD { padding: 10px 12px; background-image: url('img/dot-yellow.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
</style>

<p><span class="outlineS"></span><span class="graphicD"></span><span class="textS"></span>Item 1</p>
<p><span class="outlineS"></span>Item 2</p>
<p><span class="graphicS">Item 3</p>
<p>Item 4</p>
```

I am sure I could create a bunch of little `span` fillers to put wherever I don't want an image, but at some point it is just creating a lot of messy code for something that seems like it should be more simple.

All ideas are welcome, including using other forms of tags besides the current `<p>` / `<span>` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thomas I added the fixed result, hope it is helpful for you~

```css
p {
      padding-left: 90px;
      position: relative;
    }

    p > span {
      width: 14px;
      height: 14px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-style: solid;
    }

    p > span.empty {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .outlineS {
      left: 0;
      background-color: blue;
      border-color: blue;
    }

    .graphicS {
      left: 30px;
      background-color: green;
      border-color: green;
    }

    .textS {
      left: 60px;
      background-color: yellow;
      border-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<p><span class="outlineS"></span><span class="graphicS empty"></span><span class="textS"></span>Item 1</p>
    <p><span class="outlineS"></span>Item 2</p>
    <p><span class="graphicS"></span>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
```

Comment: I actually have a six images, two of each color.  There is a solid dot image version (the ones shown) and an empty circle or donut image of each color.  I have updated my question to show this.

Comment: Edited, so you can add "empty" class name what you want empty dot - only border.

Comment: That is really nice.  No images needed, just pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Done using `display: grid;` and CSS variables for the color

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0 }
* { box-sizing: border-box }

p {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 20px 20px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

p .outlineS, p .outlineO {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

p .graphicS, p .graphicO {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

p .textS, p .textO {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
P span:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

p span:not(:last-child) { height: 20px }

p span:not(:last-child)::before {
  background-color: var(--background);
  border: 2px solid var(--border);
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: translate(2.5px, 2.5px);
}

.outlineS::before { --background: blue; --border: blue; }
.outlineO::before { --background: transparent; --border: blue; }

.graphicS::before { --background: green; --border: green; }
.graphicO::before { --background: transparent; --border: green; }

.textS::before { --background: yellow; --border: yellow; }
.textO::before { --background: transparent; --border: yellow; }
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="outlineS"></span>
  <span class="graphicO"></span>
  <span class="textS"></span>
  <span>Item 1</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="outlineS"></span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="graphicS"></span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>Item 4</span>
</p>
```